# Why is my variable of type ListUsersRequest not realizing it has a method called withFilter(String)?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

So I am in java trying to connect to my AWS Cognito User pool and load a user with a given uuid. I have succesfully loaded all the users in the user pool but now want to load only one with a specific uuid. To do this I must create a ListUsersRequest object and set it's userPoolId and filter. I would do this like so:

```
ListUsersRequest listUsersRequest = new ListUsersRequest();
listUsersRequest.withUserPoolId("us-east-1_m86wIbRdI");
listUsersRequest.withFilter("sub=97aca512-d186-4fb0-a74a-737s1f4361e5");
```

But this is being VERY strange. Eclipse tells me withFilter(String) is not a method that belongs to the ListUsersRequest type. This is not true, the documentation and every example I have found tell me withFilter is a method on the class. Is there another way to do this or is the documentation I am looking at deprecated or something?

I tried this which looked like it could be an alternate to the filter but while it runs fineit doesn't do any filter and just returns all users.

```
listUsersRequest.putCustomQueryParameter("sub", "97aca512-d186-4fb0-a74a-737s1f4361e5");
```

This is my import line:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.ListUsersRequest;
```

any idea?

Comment: Are you sure that you have imported the correct `ListUsersRequest`?

Comment: Yes, almost positive as all the other methods for the Class work fine. And I have even used it without putting a filter and the class works as expected returning all users. I am aware there is another class in the AWS java sdk called ListUsersRequest but I have imported the Cognito one. This is such a bizarre error.

Comment: i added the import line I used here if that helps

Comment: Maybe the version (jar?) in your eclipse is too old - seems that method has been added later.

Comment: Any idea where I can get the updated version of this jar from to try that?

Comment: Here? https://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/

Comment: I tried updating my version of eclipse and install updates on my aws stuff within eclipse but it is still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are importing the right class, because there are 2 classes with that name:

The one you want (and has the right methods):
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidp/model/ListUsersRequest.html

And another one:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/model/ListUsersRequest.html

If you import the right one, are you sure you have the latest version of the SDK ?

Comment: Pretty sure I have the right class, I was aware of the other one with the same name but my import looks like it is accessing the correct one. How would I check/update my version of the SDK in Eclipse?

Comment: That depends on how you added the sdk, according to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-install.html you could have done it with maven, gradle, eclipse toolkit ...

Comment: Ok so I checked the aws docs here:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html and noted the latest version of the java sdk is 1.11.121. I checked my projects in eclipse and it said the AWS SDK for Java was being read from the file /aws-java-sdk/1.11.121 so it looks like it is the most recent version of the java sdk. Any other ideas? I don't understand